# Finding the mass generating function of a continuous random variable given a pdf

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

The pdf is given, $$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Where $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$, $\sigma>0$, $\mu\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

$$M_X(t)=E(e^{xt})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{xt}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

I've been working on this one a while, but the complexity of the exponents of the e's is really throwing me off. Any hints/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a _mass_ generating function? Something like a Twinkies bar?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

1) expand (x-\mu)^2

2) combine the exponents of $e$ and comlete the square in $x$

3) calculate the new integral which is a Gauss integral.

Answer (score 0):

We want $E(e^{Xt})$. We could integrate directly. It is a little messy, not terrible. But it is easier to note that $X=\mu+\sigma Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal. So we want $E(e^{(\mu +\sigma Z)t})$, where $Z$ is standard normal. This simplifies to  $e^{\mu t} E(e^{\sigma t Z})$. 
Now 
$$E(e^{\sigma t Z})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\sigma t z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz.$$
Forget about the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ at the bottom for a while. We are basically integrating $\exp(-z^2/2 +\sigma t z)$.
The exponent is 
$$-\frac{z^2-2\sigma t z}{2}.$$
**Complete the square**. We get
$$\exp(-z^2/2 +\sigma t z)=\exp\left(-\frac{(z-\sigma t)^2 +\sigma^2 t^2}{2}\right).$$

Thus
$$E(e^{Xt})=e^{\mu t} e^{\sigma^2 t^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(z-\sigma t)^2/2}\,dz.$$ 
The remaining integral is $1$, as can be shown by letting $u=z-\sigma t$.